# Lax-Milgram and the existence of solution to parabolic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I think it is standard and common to use Lax-Milgram theorem to prove the existence of solution to elliptic equation. However, can we use it to establish the existence of parabolic equation? I do not find some examples in standard PDE textbooks.

Suppose I have a parabolic equation
$$ \partial_t u - \partial_{x_j}(a_{ij} \partial_{x_i} u) + b_i \partial_{x_i} u + c u =f(x,t)$$
on $\Omega \times [0,T]$. Then the weak formulation should be
$$ \int_{\Omega} \partial_{t} u \varphi + a_{ij} \partial_{x_i} u \partial_{x_j} \varphi + b_i \partial_{x_i} u \varphi + c u \varphi-f\varphi=0,$$
for all $\varphi(x) \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and a.e. $t\in[0,T]$. But I do not know how can we define the bilinear mapping in this way. May I get some help?

Comment: I have seen Wiki for the Lions–Lax–Milgram theorem. The page mentions that it can be applied to heat equation, but I do not think it is obvious.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem

Comment: I haven't looked into it proper, but google gave me this https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~mischler/Enseignements/IntroEvolPDE/chap1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the exact theorem from Chapter 3.1.2 in the book "Elliptic & Parabolic Equations" written by Zhuoqun Wu, Jingxue Yin and Chunpeng Wang.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Have you ever figured out how to solve heat equation using Lax-Milgram theorem.