# Solving heat equation with Lax-Milgram theory

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

I'm interested in proving the existence of parabolic equations using Lax-Milgram theory, and I saw this question: [Lax-Milgram and the existence of solution to parabolic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217484/lax-milgram-and-the-existence-of-solution-to-parabolic-equation). I have read the book it mentions, where the author uses a "modified Lax-Milgram theorem" which I did't see in any other contexts. I wonder whether there are any other references in this subject.

Also, in the quoted MSE question, a wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem) is mentioned in the comments. In the wiki page, it is said **we can use classical Lax-Milgram theory to solve heat equation**. However, no other details are mentioned there. I believe the "classical Lax-Milgram theory" here is different from the "modified Lax-Milgram theorem" in the aforementioned book.

**I really wish to see a more detailed description on how to solve heat equation using classical Lax-Milgram theory.** I think it can give us more insights on parabolic pdes. Thank you if you would like to help.

Comment: In the linked post a comment (by Calvin Khor) links to [this](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~mischler/Enseignements/IntroEvolPDE/chap1.pdf) document. In section 4 (page 6) Lax-Milgram is applied to show the existence of solution for a parabolic evolution equation, which generalizes the heat equation. Take $a=c=b=0$ and you recover the heat equation.